# Alternative for reserved word "group"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, ruby-on-rails-4, reserved-words

I take naming seriously because it even appears to the user in many places by default.

I would like to create a model named Group, which refers to something similar to Facebook groups.

Because group is very common I hoped that it was possible to use it as other common words (e.g. date), but... it is a reserved word in SQL and it is also an ActiveRecord method (i.e. `Model.group(*args)`).

I really cannot find a valid (and generic as I need) synonym: how should I behave in this case? Is there any convention or any common replacement for the word "group"?

Comment: Group a reserved word? where did you see that?

Comment: I have updated the question. Here where I found that it is reserved: http://latheesh.com/2010/02/02/rails-reserved-words/

Comment: Do you think I can use it as a Model and Table name? I thought I should avoid it because I usually get strange bugs when I use words that are reserved in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but a coworker sent me this and I had to correct him.

**The solution is quoting your identifiers**. Then there is no problem. In Mysql we quote with backticks (`):

```
MariaDB [some_db]> create view `group` as (select 1 as one);

MariaDB [some_db]> select * from `group`;
+-----+
| one |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+
```

In Postgresql you have to use the normal double quote (") instead: `select * from "group";`. In MSSQL,you use square brackets ([]): `select * from [group];`.

There are many reserved words in SQL and new may be added. Always quote your identifiers unless you're sure they free.

**Active Record** should quote all identifiers by default. If it forgets in some case then that may be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an adjective (i.e. PrivateGroup, as all my groups are private).

Any better idea is welcome.